# Does the Dragonfly Spec mod work with Explosive Payload perk?

Tags: destiny-2

I have a sniper rifle which has the Explosive Payload perk. I'm interested to know if it's worth putting a Dragonfly Spec mod into the weapon.

So does the Dragonfly Spec mod only work with Dragonfly perk, or does it work with Explosive Payload as well?

The details are,

**Dragonfly**
Precision kills create an elemental damage explosion.

**Explosive Payload**
Projectiles create an area-of-effect detonation on impact.

**Dragonfly Spec**
Increase damage and radius of Dragonfly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.

I did some experiments with the Dragonfly Spec mod and Explosive Payload, and the explosion did not increase in size.

So it's safe to assume that Dragonfly Spec only applies to the Dragonfly perk.